# Getting error as Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I'm trying to build my solution with existing build definition.

Here is the issue: I added a new separate solution to existing project. Existing project is on .net standard and mine is on .net framework (console + class library).

Existing project is building fine but when I try to initiate the build its getting failed with `Please specify package direcotry ...`:

> Found in Parent NuGet.Config they mentioned as "add key="repositoryPath" value=".\packages" /"
>
> Nugets are not restoring because its unable to find C:\users\xyz\packages folder" ..."[error]build\CBT\build.props(96,5): Error CBT.NuGet.1000: NuGet packages were not restored and the build cannot continue.  Refer to other errors for more information."

Comment: Did you put your solution file in the same folder as the other pre-existing solution file?

Comment: It would help if you could provide [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because it's not clear what you're doing. Normally NuGet only asks you to specify a PackagesDirectory or SolutionDirectory when you use nuget.exe to restore a packages.config file. If you're not running "nuget restore packages.config" yourself (or run a build script that does this), I don't know how you could have got this message. If you're using nuget.exe, you should restore the .sln file, but if you open the solution in Visual Studio, it should restore automatically (and never give that error message)